# Complexity of BST

Tags: time-complexity, asymptotics, search-algorithms, search-trees

I have the following pseudo-code for printing all nodes of a BST :

```
traverse(x):
    if x == nil:
        return
    else:
        print x
        traverse(x.left)
        traverse(x.right)
```

I want to find its complexity. I have an idea, but I'm not sure if I am implementing it correctly.

$T(n) = 2T(n-1) + cn$

Where $T(n-1)$ for each recursive call and $cn$ for the return statement.

Is my solution correct?

Comment: Is $n$ the number of nodes? If so, your recurrence gives $O(n^2)$ which is apparently wrong because you are just traversing each node once.

Comment: @hengxin hmmm, you're right. But then what would I put in place of `T(n-1)`, `T(1)`?

Comment: I don't think there is an absolute answer here. The recurrence depends on the structure of your BST tree. And are you considering the worst-case time complexity or the average-case time complexity? More importantly, you don't need a recurrence to figure out the time complexity of your algorithm. It is $\Theta(n)$.

Comment: every time I post a question concerning constant time, someone flags it as a dupe of the question above ^^^. I'm asking for help for a specific problem, and the question that is referenced above does not entirely help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i said in previous reply was about finding a node. I excuse for misunderstanding your question. For worst case its the same but for printing in average case it's $T(n)=2T(n/2)+1$ which is $O(n)$.

Answer (score 1):

It sometimes helps to start by seeing what an algorithm does, rather than immediately jumping to computing the timing. In your case, you're generating a [preorder traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) of a binary tree:

```
visit (node x)                // x is the root node of the tree being visited
   if x exists
      print the value in x
      visit (x's left subtree)
      visit (x's right subtree)
```

For example, consider this binary tree:
[image]

Starting at the root, we print its value, $5$, and then recursively visit the left subtree (the $2, 8, 4$ piece). The root of that subtree is the $2$ node, so that would be printed next. Continuing this way, we print $5, 2, 8, 4$ and backtrack from the $4$ node to the $8$ node, continuing until we find a right subtree to visit, namely the right subtree of the $5$ node. We then visit the $7, 1, 3, 6$ subtree, from left to right at each subtree. The traversal will then be
$$
5\quad2\quad8\quad4\quad7\quad1\quad3\quad6
$$
Now that we see what the algorithm does, let's see how long it takes. There are two important parts: printing the node values and then recursively printing the values in the left and right subtrees. For a tree with $n$ nodes we'll print $n$ values. We get to each of these print statements as part of a function call, so there will also be $n$ function calls. The total amount of work done, then will be $2n$ so $T(n)=\Theta(n)$. Note that the timing will not depend on the shape of the tree, only on the number of nodes in the tree.

Answer (score 0):

Complexity of a BST differs in different cases. In worst case BST is is like a linear linked list (all sub nodes are only left-child or right-child of each other) which its complexity can be measured by solving following recursive equation:

$T(n)=T(n-1)+1$ which is $O(n)$. But for average case we can consider it as a complete binary tree so $T(n)=T(n/2)+1$ and it's complexity is $O(log(n))$ which $log(n)$ is height of the tree.

Comment: $T(n) = 2T(n/2) + 1$ does not give you $O(\lg n)$. $T(n) = T(n/2) + 1$ does.

Comment: @hengxin I think you're right, $T(n) = 2T(n/2) + 1$ gives $O(n lg n)$, correct?

Comment: Yea, i made it mistake while typing it. Its $T(n)=Tn/2)+1$ becuase you only search one of the sub trees. Right or left.

Comment: @Bolboa The OP does not search some element. The algorithm prints all the elements. So, $T(n) = T(n/2) + 1$ is *not* correct here. And, $T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n$ gives $O(n \lg n)$.